# How do I customise my login page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created the stock ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2013.  After customising the master page, I wanted to add the ability to login from anywhere rather than directing the user to /Account/Login.aspx.  So I added a drop down form in the header of the master page.
I copied the relevant code from login.aspx.cs to Site.Master.cs,

```
        protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user password
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

            // This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    //string youruser = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
                    //Session["YourUser"] = youruser;
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                                                    Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                                                    RememberMe.Checked),
                                      true);
                    break;
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

all the declarations

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using OnStageTonightWebForms.Models;
```

and this line

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Account/OpenAuthProviders.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="OpenAuthProviders" %>
```

However, when I run the app, it throws the error "The name 'IsValid' does not exist in the current context" and in the code there is a red wiggly line under IsValid.  There are no red lines in login.aspx.cs.

The code is identical between the two files, so why does one work but not the other?

Comment: Are you sure they are identical? try Page.IsValid.

Comment: They should be identical,  I copy and pasted the lot over.

Comment: Many thanks, that's stopped the error and the app runs now.  I just to need to put some LoginViews to make sure it worked.